# Trying to prove Master Theorem from $T(n) = aT(n/b) + f(n)$

Tags: number-theory, algorithms, recurrence-relations, recursion

Let's consider a recurrence of form $T(n) = aT(n/b) + f(n)$ where $n = b^k$ for simplicity. Then $T(n/b^k) = T(n/n) = T(1)$ but I don't know what we're usually supposed to set $T(1)$ equal to at the bottom of the recursion (a constant? $f(1)$? What?).

Then I am trying to solve the recurrence first by unrolling it:

$T(n) = aT(n/b) + f(n)$

$T(n) = a^2T(n/b^2) + af(n/b) + f(n)$

$T(n) = a^3T(n/b^3) + a^2f(n/b^2) + af(n/b) + f(n)$

...

$T(n) = a^kT(n/b^k) + \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} a^i f(n/b^i)$

If $T(1) = f(1)$ then:

$T(n) = \sum_{i=0}^{k} a^i f(n/b^i) = \sum_{i=0}^{\log_b(n)} a^i f(n/b^i)$

However I look up http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs3110/2011sp/Lectures/lec19-master/mm-proof.pdf and they say it's

$T(n) = O(n^{\log_b(a)}) + \sum_{i=0}^{\log_b(n)} a^i f(n/b^i)$

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: What if $n/b$ is not an integer?

Comment: @Slade I mentioned that $n = b^k$ so that it would always be divisible by $b$. Technically I believe you could also use the floor function and it wouldn't affect the big-O anyway.

Comment: Okay.  I think the problem is that you're assuming $T(1)=f(1)$.  It could be any constant.

Comment: So then we have $a^{\log_b(n)} \cdot c_0$ for some constant $c_0$? for that piece?

Comment: Yes.  That's exactly what's in the link.  Note that $a^{\log_b{n}} = n^{\log_b{a}}$.

Comment: Whoa, I didn't know you could do that. Is that always true?

Comment: Yes.  One way to see it: $n^{\frac{1}{\log_b n}} = n^{\log_n b} = b$.  Similarly, $a^{\frac{1}{\log_b a}} = a^{\log_a b} = b$.  So $n^{\frac{1}{\log_b n}} = a^{\frac{1}{\log_b a}}$, therefore $n^{\log_b a} = a^{\log_b n}$.

Comment: Maybe it's simpler to just reason directly: $a^{\log_b n} = n^{\log_n a \cdot \log_b n} = n^{\log_b a}$

Comment: Does this work? If $a^{\log_b(n)} = x$ take the $\log_b$ of both sides and we expand to $\log_b(n)\log_b(a) = \log_b(x)$. Swap the items on the lefthand side to $\log_b(a)\log_b(n) = \log_b(x)$ and do $b$ raised to both sides to revert back to $n^{\log_b(a)} = x$?

Comment: Yes, it works.  You can do the same argument with any base logarithm, doesn't have to be b.

Answer (score 0):

You did it correctly and it seems like the summation $\sum_{i=0}^{\log_b n}$ in the course notes should be $\sum_{i=0}^{\log_b n - 1}$.  Your formula $T(n) = a^k T(n/b^k) + \sum_{i=0}^{\log_b a - 1} a^i f(n/b^i)$ simplifies to 
$T(n) = a^{\log_b n} T(1) +  \sum_{i=0}^{\log_b a - 1} a^i f(n/b^i) = n^{\log_b a} T(1) + \sum_{i=0}^{\log_b a - 1} a^i f(n/b^i) = \Theta(n^{\log_b a}) +\sum_{i=0}^{\log_b a - 1} a^i f(n/b^i)$.