# Master theorem proof about relationships $T(n)=aT(n/b)+f(n)$

Tags: algorithms, recurrence-relations, computational-complexity, recursive-algorithms

I am reading the proof of Master theorem from Cornell University lectures:
https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs3110/2012sp/lectures/lec20-master/mm-proof.pdf

[image]

I am having problem in this step:

$$n^{log_ba-\epsilon} \frac{b^{\epsilon (log_bn+1)} - 1}{b^\epsilon - 1} = n^{log_ba-\epsilon} \frac{b^{\epsilon} n^\epsilon - 1}{b^\epsilon - 1}$$

So how did author claim:

$$b^{(log_bn+1)} = n^\epsilon$$

I understand it is some epsilon > 0, but how can you put an equal sign between two expressions like that?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I have taken the liberty to modify your title in order for it to be more "understandable/searchable" (Any important theorem can be called "master theorem" !)

Comment: @JeanMarie, Thank you for that, it is much better :)

Comment: Related : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2241952

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this
$$
\begin{align}
b^{\epsilon(\log_b n + 1)} &= b^{\epsilon \log_b n} b^{\epsilon} \\
&= b^{\log_b n^{\epsilon}} b^{\epsilon} \\
&= n^{\epsilon}b^{\epsilon}
\end{align}
$$